# Rails weird delete behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Sorry for the "weird" in the subject, here is what is happening.

I have a ActiveRecord object that looks like:

```
class BraintreeCache < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :company, :foreign_key => :subscription_id
serialize :subscription
serialize :credit_card
end
```

Executing:

```
BraintreeCache.delete(:subscription_id => "12")
```

Will return:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "id"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "braintree_caches" WHERE "id"."subscription_id" ...
                                             ^
: DELETE FROM "braintree_caches" WHERE "id"."subscription_id" = '12'
```

What is going on here? Where does the "id" come from?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

So what got me very confused is that I have branch this delete is working on.

The correct syntax should be:

```
BraintreeCache.delete_all(:subscription_id => "42")
```

I still can't figure out how the simple delete was working.

Regards,

Comment: Thats interesting. It looks better without `where`.

Comment: And about simple delete, it accepts only id or array of ids: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete/class

Answer (score 0):

It probably comes from misusing of `delete` method. Try this instead:

```
BraintreeCache.where(:subscription_id => "12").delete_all
```

Comment: for a bad subscription_id you will get ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
 from (irb):19:in `delete'
 from (irb):19

Answer (score 0):

The static [delete](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-delete) method expects an ID as the first argument, not a hash. Try this:

```
BraintreeCache.find_by_subscription_id("12").delete
```

EDIT:

If you don't want to have to instantiate the object first, you could also use the [delete_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all) method:

```
BraintreeCache.delete_all(subscription_id: "12")
```

Comment: If I have a missing id this will break with "NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!"

Comment: Check for nil then. Or use `.try(:delete)`. But why would you have to delete something that doesn't exist?